# `register' an overloaded operator in python

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword

Normally, when I am overloading an operator (say: `__repr__`) in a class, I have the luxury of knowing what I want to do from the beginning, eg:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Rep:Foo("+str(self.a)+")"
```

In this case if I run `>>>Foo(3)` in the interpreter I get back `Rep:Foo(3)`.

Recently I wanted to add such an overloaded operator to an existing instance of a class, eg:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

f = Foo(3)
f.__repr__ = lambda s: "Rep:Foo("+str(s.a)+")"
```

However, in this case running `>>>f` ignores the custom `__repr__` function and returns the standard representation (`<__main__.Foo object at ...`). Even `>>>f.__repr__()` does not work, instead, I have to use `>>>f.__repr__(f)` to get the "desired" result.

Purely out of curiosity (even if this worked, it would not help me too much), I then tried adding the operator directly during the initiation, but as an "attribute" rather than using `def`, i.e.:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.__repr__ = lambda s: "Rep:Foo("+str(s.a)+")"
```

This was no better than my previous attempt, i.e., `>>>Foo(3)` again returns the "standard" representation rather than my intended string.

Why is this happening (what am I missing about operator overloading)? And, can I somehow achieve my goal (Is it possible to make an existing python class recognise and properly "connect" a newly overloaded operator)?

Comment: Instance or class, which one is your target?

Comment: Operators and methods are *by definition* on the class. Any operations such as ``self.__repr__ = lambda ...`` merely creates an attribute on the instance, one which just happens to be callable.

Comment: You are overriding the method, not overloading it.

Comment: @superbrain my target was the class, though I am glad you have discussed the other case in the accepted answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating a `__repr__` attribute that belongs to the instance `f`  in the first example or `self` in the second example (which would mean every instance, but still at the instance level). What you need to do is assign it to the `__repr__` attr of the `Foo` class to overload its method.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

Foo.__repr__ = lambda s: "Rep:Foo("+str(s.a)+")"
Foo(3)
```

If you wanted to achieve this just at an instance basis, this is, only overload it for an instance, I'm sorry to tell you that you can't do it. `repr(...)` doesn't look at the instance attributes for `__repr__`, it only does so in the attributes of the class. A workarround suggested by @superbrain in the comments to this would be making the class `__repr__` method look for a `__repr__` attribute in the instance, then use it, and if it can't find it use the default class method.

Comment: @superbrain in order to achieve the same behavior as the first snippet in the question (`def` inside the `class` declaration) the one you need to overload is the class attribute. `repr(...)` will not look for instace's `__repr__` attributes.

Comment: @superbrain `need`may be a more precise verb in this case, changed it already. Also added a small explanation that this can't be achieven in an instance basis.

Comment: I guess per-instance could be achieved with a `__repr__` on the class that then uses a `_repr` on the instance (if it exists)...

Comment: @superbrain delegating to the instance from the class would be a workarround, yes.